# Command "git status" listing more commits than "git log"

Tags: git

I did some work in a topic branch, with two intermediate commits before finishing the work. Then I went back to master and merged my topic branch. I'm in the habit of merging with `--no-commit`, so I can check that everything is ok before committing, but this was a fast-forward and I didn't stop it with --no-ff. Now "git status" tells me that there are 5 commits to push, but "git log" only shows 3 – the number of commits I did on the topic branch:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git log
commit f4474af2add220b1c2f0bf07d92f5035cef622ef (HEAD -> notifiche, master)
Author: Francesco Marchetti-Stasi <f.marchettistasi@***>
Date:   Fri Dec 10 14:55:48 2021 +0100

    [...]

commit b63a44f7c1266a53a0e5c91a3395fc9eb75d9bd2
Author: Francesco Marchetti-Stasi <f.marchettistasi@***>
Date:   Tue Dec 7 16:46:59 2021 +0100

    [...]

commit beb5d335e0ac35184b6a8e78bf45627e705a2a9b
Merge: 1f16a0d 025f660
Author: Francesco Marchetti-Stasi <f.marchettistasi@***>
Date:   Tue Dec 7 16:46:18 2021 +0100

    [...]

commit 025f660ebc22b2d3bee00c691657c6e7318fcf50 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: Francesco Marchetti-Stasi <f.marchettistasi@***>
Date:   Tue Dec 7 11:44:48 2021 +0100

    [...]

commit 1f16a0dcd96862b0ca75d3f3ca896ad755ccf29e
Author: Francesco Marchetti-Stasi <f.marchettistasi@***>
Date:   Thu Nov 25 09:38:21 2021 +0100

    [...]
```

Is this normal? Are there some "hidden" commits I am not seeing?

In your answers please consider I may need to push my commits, but I guess that shouldnt' change local commit history, correct?

EDIT: in reply to Lasse V. Karlsen question:

```
$ git log --format="%h %d"
8059943  (HEAD -> master)
b63a44f
beb5d33
025f660  (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
1f16a0d
0bd94aa
1e9d375  (dizione_e_sede)
c19c33a
c2bc958
d1801c3
1dd9a87
e4f0846
2091d2e  (origin/conv_pdf)
84076f3
[...]
$ git log --format="%h %d" origin/master..master
8059943  (HEAD -> master)
b63a44f
beb5d33
1f16a0d
0bd94aa
$
```

And on the server I see the following:

[image: 025f660e X 1e9d3754 c19c33a7]

On hover on the red circled X a message "Pipeline: failed" appears.

I should also mention that we upgraded our gitlab server from a very old version to 14.4.1, right in the middle of these commits – may this be related?...

Comment: What does `git log origin/master..master` tell you?

Comment: Try adding `--full-history`. `git log` ordinarily doesn't show you merged commits that didn't contribute anything, see "history simplification" in its docs.

Comment: The red circled X has nothing to do with Git, really; it's an indication that a CI job failed on the contents of that particular commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal.  The `git status` command that shows that you are five commits ahead is correct (modulo bugs in Git, which are relatively rare).  The `git log` output you see is *also* correct, but contains a subtle kind of lie:

> ```
> commit f4474af2add220b1c2f0bf07d92f5035cef622ef (HEAD -> notifiche, master)
> Author: Francesco Marchetti-Stasi <f.marchettistasi@***>
> Date:   Fri Dec 10 14:55:48 2021 +0100
>
>     [...]
>
> commit b63a44f7c1266a53a0e5c91a3395fc9eb75d9bd2
> Author: Francesco Marchetti-Stasi <f.marchettistasi@***>
> Date:   Tue Dec 7 16:46:59 2021 +0100
>
>     [...]
>
> commit beb5d335e0ac35184b6a8e78bf45627e705a2a9b
> Merge: 1f16a0d 025f660
> ```

When `git log` shows commits, it does so using a fairly complicated internal algorithm that uses a priority queue.  This handles the fact that the commit graph is a DAG, not a simple tree.  In particular *merge commits* result in tricky traversals.

Note that the third commit in the list here is in fact a merge commit, with two parents: `1f16a0d` (shortened) and `025f660` (also shortened).

The *next* commit that `git log` shows you, in its linearized sequence, is:

> ```
> commit 025f660ebc22b2d3bee00c691657c6e7318fcf50 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
> Author: Francesco Marchetti-Stasi <f.marchettistasi@***>
> Date:   Tue Dec 7 11:44:48 2021 +0100
> ```

or `025f660`: this is the *second parent* of the merge.  This is the commit that `origin/master` names.

The commit that `git log` shows *after* `025f660` is:

> ```
> commit 1f16a0dcd96862b0ca75d3f3ca896ad755ccf29e
> Author: Francesco Marchetti-Stasi <f.marchettistasi@***>
> Date:   Thu Nov 25 09:38:21 2021 +0100
> ```

which is the *first* parent of that merge.  The reason it gets shown after, rather than before, is that its time stamp (in late Nov) is earlier than the time stamp of `025f660` (7 Dec of the same year).

This is all clearer, in my opinion at least, if we *draw a graph*.  Here's a partial graph of what you're seeing, where I have replaced each commit's big ugly hash ID with a simple `o` or `*` or `●`:

```
...--●--o--o---*--o--o   <-- master
      \       /
       ●-----●   <-- origin/master
```

The commit marked `*` is the merge commit.  The commits whose hash ID has been replaced by a black circle `●` are on *both branches*; the other commits are only on `master`.  There are four open circles and the one starred merge, so there are five commits on `master` that are not on `origin/master`.

This graph can be drawn any number of ways:<sup>1</sup> using `git log --graph`, or `git log --graph --oneline`, will make Git draw one for you, vertically oriented with the newest commit at the top.  Because `git log` outputs commits one at a time, any sequence that *doesn't* include the graph, but does include a merge commit, must necessarily be some kind of lie (of omission or commission, depending on what you'd prefer and how you view this) when it implies a simple linear chain of commits.  That's because the merge commit ties together some otherwise separate-but-parallel chains.  The log command must walk both sides of the chain, or omit one side of the chain, and whichever choice you tell it to make, the result will be either incomplete ("walk just the first-parent links") or incorrect-or-incomplete based on your viewpoint.

---

<sup>1</sup>Here's an alternative drawing that, I think, makes the situation clearer in most cases, though `git log --graph` won't draw anything like this at all:

```
       o--o
      /    \
...--●      *--o--o   <-- master
      \    /
       ●--●   <-- origin/master
```

This is how I like to lay out my drawings where I show how `git merge` works.

---

#### Optional reading: some further details

The `git log` algorithm uses a *priority queue*.

The code begins by seeding the queue with one or more starting point commits (if there are no starting point commits, `git log` does nothing, but the default is to use the `HEAD` commit, and `HEAD` almost always specifies a commit: the exception is when you are on a branch that does not exist, which Git calls an *orphan branch* or an *unborn branch*—Git is not consistent about which term it uses).  That is:

```
git log
```

inserts the `HEAD` commit (only) into the queue, while:

```
git log --branches
```

inserts all branch-tip commits into the queue, and:

```
git log master origin/master
```

inserts the commits identified by the names `master` and `origin/master` (this may be one single commit, if both names select the same commit, or two separate commits as in your case).

Because the queue *is* a priority queue, if it contains more than one entry, the "front" entry is the one with the highest priority.  This is controlled by various options to `git log`, such as `--date-order`, `--author-date-order`, or `--topo-order`, but the default is to use the committer timestamp (which is not shown by default: the dates you see here are author dates; but fortunately most commits have the *same* author and committer date), with the latest timestamp—the most recent commit—having the highest priority.

If the queue has only *one* entry, of course, that one entry has the *only* priority, which is therefore the highest, average, and lowest priority all at the same time.  So that's a degenerate case—but an important one since very often, there's only one entry *in* the queue.  For instance, that's the case for your `git log`, which inserts just the `HEAD` commit, which is also the `master` commit.

The log code now runs a loop:

- while the queue is not empty

  - remove the front entry (a commit)
  - decide whether to show this commit

    - if so, show it (there's a special bit of weirdness with `--reverse` here though)
  - decide which parent(s) if any to insert into the queue

The defaults for the two "decide" steps are: yes, do show it; insert all parents.

Most commits have just one parent, so for the first commit—identified by `HEAD` and `notifiche` and `master`—the loop shows that one commit, "decorated" with the two branch names, and inserts its one parent `b63a44f7c1266a53a0e5c91a3395fc9eb75d9bd2`.

The queue now has one commit in it, so the loop runs and shows the *second* commit.  There are no names for that commit—no branch identifiers, no tags, etc.—so we just see that commit, without `(origin/master)` or anything.  The parent has one parent too, so that one parent goes into the queue: we're now at `beb5d335e0ac35184b6a8e78bf45627e705a2a9b`, which is the merge commit.

The queue now has one commit in it, so the loop runs and shows the third commit.  This commit has *two* parents, `1f16a0d` and `025f660`.  They're both inserted into the priority queue.

Now we hit the priority code: the queue has two entries.  One of them is at the front.  The `git log` code extracts that one.  It's the second parent, but it's the higher priority because it has a later committer timestamp.

The `git log` code now shows *this* commit, which *is* named by one name, `origin/master`, so now you see the misleading output.  That commit has one parent, which goes into the queue, which continues to have two elements in it.

This pattern repeats until the branching implied by going backwards through the merge is itself resolved.  Once there's only one commit *in* the queue, we return to the normal single-threaded walk.  (Using `--topo-order` makes sure that this happens as soon as possible, and `--graph` implies `--topo-order`.)

Comment: This is the _second_ time you answered a git question of mine with clear and thorough details. Many thanks, you are one of the persons making stackoverflow valuable!

Answer (score 2):

Try using from CLI (command line):

```sh
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
```

or if you have a GUI (on windows or Linux or Mac):

```
gitk --all
```

This will allow you to see the history in a more visually appealing way. I believe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: This just changes the git log visualization, it doesn't solve the underlying issue

Comment: @azbarcea: for the OP's needs, you can drop the `--all` (or explain what he can see with it), and explain how these commands help to solve his issue (e.g : both `--graph`and `gitk` give a graphical view of how commits are connected)

Comment: @Paolo It won't *fix* the problem, but it will reveal if there even *is* a problem. The various logs shown in the question don't really fit together, at least not in an obvious way.

Comment: It certainly helps, but needs further clarifications – see the accepted (and very detailed) answer.